# File already in used by another process. while saving file

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, tiff

I have document processor that extract thumbnails and Large images from tiff file.

But i get **"file already in use"** and **"A generic error occurred in GDI+"** error most frequently.

There three basic functions:

1. Get tiff pages count
2. Get all thumbnails
3. Get all large images

The file stream is used in all three operations.

Is there any way that I can use the file stream once, save a copy of the file in memory and release the file for other use.

I tried this:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    photo = Image.FromStream(fs, true, false);                                
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();                                
}

using (photo)
{
    //dummy hight and width passed to function.
    generateThumbNails(photo,1,90,90);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension dimention = new FrameDimension(photo.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
    total = photo.GetFrameCount(dimention);
    photo.Dispose();
}
```

generateThumbNails function:

```
public static Bitmap GenerateThumbNails(System.Drawing.Image img, int curPageNo, int width, int height)
{
    System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension dimention = new FrameDimension(img.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
    img.SelectActiveFrame(dimention, curPageNo);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    g.Dispose();
    return bmp;  
}
```

But I get **"A generic error occurred in GDI+"** while re-sizing the image on the following line:

```
g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: Could you please create a [minmal, complete and verifiable code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where does your img object comes from? We need some more details.

Comment: you may review my question now.